# How to automatically assignment value to menu() in R function?

Tags: r

As follows I type code:

```
dtype <- menu(c("continuous", "binary", "ordinal", "quantal", 
                "continuous, clustered", "quantal, clustered", "continuous, summary data", 
                "quantal, CxT", "other"), title = "\nWhat type of response data do you want to consider?")
3
dtype
```

and assignment 1 to dtype, but it can't work in R function.

```
test <- function(type){
   dtype <- menu(c("continuous", "binary", "ordinal", "quantal", 
                   "continuous, clustered", "quantal, clustered", "continuous, summary data", 
                   "quantal, CxT", "other"), title = "\nWhat type of response data do you want to consider?")
   type
   return(dtype)
 }
test(type=1)
```

I change type as eval(expression(type)) and also not work.
Does anyone know how to modify this code to get the right result?

This is an example:

```
rm(list=ls())

library("tcltk")
library("gWidgets")
library("digest")
library("assertive")
library("gWidgetstcltk")
library("proast38.9")

# data
jia_data <-list(dose = c(0.94,3.35,7.08,15.41),
                N = c(305,576,548,256),
                effect = c(32,106,193,156))


# transform format
data_jia_gui<-list(data = as.data.frame(jia_data),varnames = c("dose","N","effect"),nvar =3,
                   dtype= c(1,1,1))

f.proast(data_jia_gui)
4 # datatype
1 # independent variable
2 # model selection
3 # dependent variable
2 # weight
0 # corvariable
3 # BMDtype
0.10  #  BMR
1  #  
1 #plot
"hjy.txt"  #store file name
14  #exit PROAST
hjy <-read.csv2("hjy.txt",header = T , sep = "\t",skip = 2,nrows = 10)
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do. The best that I can guess is that you want to show a menu to the user, and then programmatically choose an option. Is that correct?

Comment: I want call function in a package many times,which cannot be edit and assignment value only in this menu() way.

Comment: A solution would be to overwrite the function, and removing the call to `menu()`. As the documentation of `menu()` states "_It is an error to use menu in a non-interactive session._", which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is the package and function that we are talking about? Maybe there is an alternative?

Comment: The function f.proast() in proast38.9, every variable used in this function was use menu() input, which is very inconvenient to call it in simulation.@Pieter

Comment: The core funciton   f.overlap() , f.assign(), f.change.settings(), f.con(),f.execute()  in f.proast() can not be edited, so I can not remove all menu().

Comment: library("tcltk")
library("gWidgets")
library("digest")
library("assertive")
library("gWidgetstcltk")
library("proast38.9")
# data
jia_data <-list(dose = c(0.94,3.35,7.08,15.41),
                N = c(305,576,548,256),
                effect = c(32,106,193,156))
# change formate
data_jia_gui<-list(data = as.data.frame(jia_data),varnames = c("dose","N","effect"),nvar =3,
                   dtype= c(1,1,1))

f.proast(data_jia_gui)
4 # datatlpr
1 # indepence
2 # model selection
3 # depence
2 # weight
0 # covariable
3 # BMD type
0.10  # BMR
1  # 
1 
"hjy.txt"  
14

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to refer code in commend box, I post the code in answer box.@Pieter

Comment: I have added it to your question post

Comment: Is there have any possible to use some symbol to represent input number?@Pieter

Comment: Nope, `menu()` waits for user input. That's what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could overwrite the `menu()` function to alter the behavior of the package. Your own `menu()` function should automate the choice. However, this is a very hacky solution. If others see that you are doing this, they will blame you for not being a good programmer. The better option is thus to find alternatives for the functions you are using. For example, switch to another package or dive deeper into the proast package and its source code.

If you really want to overwrite the menu function you could take a loot at this example:

```
function_that_uses_menu <- function() {
  # do something
  choice <- menu(c("one", "two"))
  # do other things
  return(choice)
}

automated_menu <- function(choices, graphics = FALSE, title = NULL) {
  return("one")
}

print(function_that_uses_menu())

function_env <- environment(menu)
original <- get("menu", envir = function_env)
assign("menu", automated_menu, envir = function_env)

print(function_that_uses_menu())
assign("menu", original, envir = function_env)
```

In this example the `menu()` function is overwritten such that `function_that_uses_menu()` uses your own defined function for `menu()`. If `function_that_uses_menu()` is inside another package (which is the case) you should first unlock its bindings before assinging it.

```
unlockBinding("menu", function_env)
assign("menu", automated_menu, envir = function_env)
```

You may want to read [this blog post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-August/171321.html) and [this chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) from Wickham's Advanced R.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm(list=ls())

library("tcltk")
library("gWidgets")
library("digest")
library("assertive")
library("gWidgetstcltk")
library("proast38.9")

# data
jia_data <-list(dose = c(0.94,3.35,7.08,15.41),
                N = c(305,576,548,256),
                effect = c(32,106,193,156))


# transform format
data_jia_gui<-list(data = as.data.frame(jia_data),varnames = c("dose","N","effect"),nvar =3,
                   dtype= c(1,1,1))

f.proast(data_jia_gui)
4 # datatype
1 # independent variable
2 # model selection
3 # dependent variable
2 # weight
0 # corvariable
3 # BMDtype
0.10  #  BMR
1  #  
1 #plot
"hjy.txt"  #store file name
14  #exit PROAST
hjy <-read.csv2("hjy.txt",header = T , sep = "\t",skip = 2,nrows = 10)
```

Comment: Could you delete this answer since it is not really an answer and I added the content to your question.