# Is it possible to program response to user input request in R?

Tags: r

I need to respond to request for user input programatically. For example, when a function `myFunction` that requests user input is called, I want to select "2" (Choice B) every time. How can I program this in? (Note: I need to leave the request for user input in, so the answer to this question is not simply to take that out).

```r
myFunction <- function(){
  value <- menu(c("Choice A", "Choice B", "Choice C"))
  return(value)
}

myFunction()
```

Requests the following user input before running anymore code. I want to slect "2" without typing anything on my keyboard (i.e., do it solely with R code).

```r
1: Choice A
2: Choice B
3: Choice C

Selection:
```

In other words, I want it to do the below automatically:

```r
Selection: 2
[1] 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend, but would you consider overwriting the `menu` function? It's a hack, I know.

Comment: I'm pretty much assuming the answer to this is going to be a hack! What do you mean by overwriting the menu function? The answer cannot change anything inside the function `myFunction` itself.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41535826/3460670) You would create a new function that is called instead of `menu`, and it could show the same choices and make an automated selection, but would not wait for an input.

Comment: Oh I see. Hmm, that *could* work. The actual scenario is a bit more complicated because I need to respond to the googlesheets4 read_sheets() authentication automatically!